# Connection header disapper when HTTP2

Tags: tcp, udp, http2, keep-alive

In making a request to my website with curl and HTTP 1.1, I see my `keep-alive` connection header explicitly:

```
$ curl https://website.com/ -i

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 2
Connection: keep-alive
```

But with Chrome's developer tool and HTTP 2 the header is missing:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 2
```

In HTTP 2 is it normal that the connection header is not sent (and why)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is normal and specified by the [HTTP/2 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-8.1.2.2).